# Python: Most computationally efficient (fastest) way to clear multiple axes in mpl

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, axes

My goal is to shave off 30-50 milliseconds from my code.

I have a mpl figure with 3 subplots. When using the animate function, I have to clear all 3 axes before each loop. This takes roughly 30 ms per axis.

What is the fastest way to do this?

So far I found:

```
    ax0.clear()
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
```

as well as:

```
    ax0.cla()
    ax1.cla()
    ax2.cla()
```

Both seem to work, but both take roughly 90 ms (in total).

I was wondering if there is something more efficient/faster than this.

Comment: `.cla()` for 3 axes: `81.7 ms ± 5.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` vs. `fig.clf()`: `4.48 µs ± 39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: Hi Trenton, I tried it, but sadly it doesn't work. I get a blank window after the first time it is applied (no repainting of subplots during each next animate loop).

Comment: Then you're probably stuck with `.cla()`

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing the axis.clear() code and manually doing only the steps that are necessary for your axes usage https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L788

Comment: blitting (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html) is probably the best way to get a performance enhancement so you only redraw the area inside the axes. Aside from that you can avoid calling `.cla()` and instead animate the individual artists. For the latter you might consider using a library like https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/animations.html